# connect.php failing to connect

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I want a website to connect to a database with a connect.php so i created a small test in it. but it is failing only showing Database Connection Failed with no mysql error. here is the code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sqluser";
$password = "Welkom01!";
$dbname = "users";

$connection = mysqli_connect('$servername', '$username', '$password');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed". mysqli_error());
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($dbname);
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error());
}
echo "succes";
?>
```

could you guys help me out? thanks in advance

Comment: You should add DB connection variable to `mysqli_error()` as in `mysqli_error($connection)` - edit: oh, and the quotes.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the parameters in your `mysqli_connect()` call.

Comment: Cool! We have your login credentials!

Comment: You also need to pass connection variable to `$select_db = mysqli_select_db($dbname);` as in `$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbname);` - Do read up on http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php and its related functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around your variables:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password');
```

PHP treats the contents of single quotes as strings. Only double quotes will evaluate variables correctly:

```
<?php
$username = 'foo';
echo '$username'; // outputs: '$username'
echo "$username"; // outputs: 'foo';
echo $username; // outputs : 'foo';
```

Also, your `mysqli_select_db` is incorrect. It should be:

```
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);
```

As Fred pointed out below, mysqli_error requires the connection to be passed in:

```
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: thanks but now the selection is failing. i tried replacing the dbname string with the database name (including and excluding single and double quotes)

Comment: +1 The only one so far who got it right, however just one small thing is missing: `mysqli_error()` requires connection be passed. Consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 1):

If you use single quotes in a method/function, the interpreter will not assign the variable value.

A solution might be:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

You also need to pass the linkid ($connection) when selecting your database.

```
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);
```

Comment: You also have a stray quote `$password'` - Consult some of the other answers, including the accepted one.

Comment: Meaning, these `($dbname, $connection)` need to be switched.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sqluser";
$password = "Welkom01!";
$dbname = "users";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed". mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection,$dbname);
if (!$select_db){
die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
echo "succes";
?>
```